# Find index where elements change value numpy

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, unique

Suppose I have

```
>>> v
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5])
```

Is there an efficient numpy way to find each index where the value changes? For instance, I would want some result like,

```
>>> index_of_changed_values(v)
[0, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

If this is not possible with some numpy routine, what is a fast way to do it in python? It would also be useful to me to be referred to some good numpy tutorials since I am a numpy beginner.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can get this functionality in numpy by comparing each element with it's neighbor;

```
v[:-1] != v[1:]


array([False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True,
    True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

to get the indices you use the "where" function

```
np.where(v[:-1] != v[1:])[0]

array([ 4,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
```

From here you can prepend the first element and add a one to get to the same indexing scheme you have in your question.

Answer (score 16):

Similar to @kith answer, but requires less massaging of the result:

```
np.where(np.roll(v,1)!=v)[0]
```

No need to prepend 0 or add 1.
Example:

```
>>> v=np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])
>>> np.where(np.roll(v,1)!=v)[0]
array([0, 3, 5, 7])
```

EDIT: as @Praveen mentioned, this fails when the last and the first elements are equal.

Comment: This won't work if the array looks something like `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]`. i.e., the first and last values are the same, so you won't get the index '0' like you expect...

Comment: @Praveen It worked for my example: `('(Hashimotos)', 2150, 2161)  :  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]` Òutput `[0, 1, 11]`

Answer (score 9):

Almost ten years later, but I came across this one today.

@kith answer is good, but may not be as neat as we want (also taking into account the steps not explicit in the answer).

that answer in the complete form would be,

```
v = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5])
np.concatenate((np.array([0]),np.where(v[:-1] != v[1:])[0]+1),axis=0)
```

An alternative I like more is,

```
np.where(np.diff(v,prepend=np.nan))[0]
```

which also returns

```
array([ 0,  5,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], dtype=int64)
```

As I said, the idea is the same as @kith's but,

- I replace `v[:-1] != v[1:]` for `np.diff()`, then in `np.where` the array is casted to boolean, this does not change much but seems neater.
- I removed the extra step of adding 1 and prepending 0. This is done by prepending `np.nan` before doing `np.diff()`. The first element of the diff output will then be `np.nan`, and in python np.nan always evaluates `True`.

Comment: hi, OP here. This is giving me some serious nostalgia for my first developer role in industry. I found out a few days ago that the team I was on at the time dissolved. Thank you guys for your answers over the years.

Comment: I'm glad it helped in any way ^_^. Stay safe.

Comment: You must have NumPy version 1.16.0 or newer installed for `np.where(np.diff(v,prepend=np.nan))[0]` to work. I'm posting for those that don't know.

Comment: @DavidM.Helmuth Good point, I honestly hadn't checked it. I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Great question and answers!

I am working with a vector with about 1 million monotonically non-decreasing integers running from 1 to 100,000 (*e.g.* `[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, ..., 100000]`). For this data set, it seems there's a noticeable performance difference between the 2 idioms discussed above and whether or not the prepend kwarg is used:

```
%timeit np.where(np.diff(v, prepend=np.nan))                                                                                                                             
15.3 ms ± 113 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit np.where(np.diff(v))[0] + 1                                                                                                                                     
7.41 ms ± 72 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit np.where(v[:-1] != v[1:])[0] + 1                                                                                                                                       
2.85 ms ± 41.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So the fancy-indexing invocation is 5 times faster compared to using diff() with the prepend kwarg and over twice as fast as using diff with no prepend (on my ancient MacBook Air anyway). For most use cases this performance difference isn't going to matter but I'm working with thousands of data sets like this (billions of rows total) so I need to keep performance in mind.