# Find index where elements change value pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Regaring to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125661/find-index-where-elements-change-value-numpy), is there a way to accomplish the same function for a pandas dataframe structure without casting it as a numpy array?

Comment: It would be better if you make this a self-contained question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Update: we can use this per @LorenzoMeneghetti

```
s[s.diff() != 0].index.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[0, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

---

```
s = pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5])

print(s.diff()[s.diff() != 0].index.values)
```

OR:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5])

print(df[0].diff()[df[0].diff() != 0].index.values)
```

Output:

```
[ 0  5  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One additional question though, why would the dataframe (from read_csv) return every index back instead of the index of when the value change? The code I use to read the csv read_csv(file, sep=',', header = None, skiprows = 1, usecols = [colNum], dtype = np.float 64, na_values = [" "]). I printed out the DataFrame from read_csv which gives me [6,6,6,6,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2] but the code df[0].diff()... returns [0,1,2,3,4...11,12,13].

Comment: I suspect that your first column or column 0 is really line number and not the changing value you are expecting.  It is hard for me to tell without the csv and the exact read statement you are doing.

Comment: Ah, thank you, it seems that I have to match the colNum with df[colNum].

Comment: why the double diff()?
Can't I just do
s[s.diff() != 0].index.values
?

Comment: @LorenzoMeneghetti honestly, that was an old answer I did when I was first learning pandas.  You are correct that is a better solution.