# Find index where elements change value (T/F) numpy

Tags: python, matrix

I have found very useful the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125661/find-index-where-elements-change-value-numpy) but I would like to use it with TRUE/FALSE values.

When I try the code I get the error message: "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: I guess you try to compare Pandas series objects, probably in the form `df.column_name`. Instead operate on `df.column_name.array` or convert them to numpy arrays.