# How to find the index where values in a list, increase value

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a list that looks like:

`mot = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]`

I need to append to a list, the index when the element changes from `0` to `1` (and not from `1` to `0`).

I've tried to do the following, but it also registers when it changes from `1` to `0`.

```
i = 0 
while i != len(mot)-1:
    if mot[i] != mot[i+1]:
        mot_daily_index.append(i)
    i += 1
```

Also, but not as important, is there a cleaner implementation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is how you can do that with a list comprehension:

```
mot = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]
mot_daily_index = [i for i,m in enumerate(mot) if i and m and not mot[i-1]]
print(mot_daily_index)
```

Output:

```
[7, 24]
```

### Explanation:

- `list(enumerate([7,5,9,3]))` will return `[(0, 7), (1, 5), (2, 9), (3, 3)]`, so the `i` in `i for i, m in enumerate`, is the index of `m` during that iteration.

Answer (score 6):

Use a list comprehension with a filter to get your indexes:

```
mot = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]

idx = [i for i,v in enumerate(mot) if i and v > mot[i-1]]
print(idx)
```

Output:

```
[7, 24]
```

Comment: Or  `i,v in enumerate(mot[1:]) if v > mot[i]`

Answer (score 5):

You could use

```
lst = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
#      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7

for index, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(lst, lst[1:])):
    if x == 0 and y == 1:
        print("Changed from 0 to 1 at", index)
```

Which yields

```
Changed from 0 to 1 at 2
Changed from 0 to 1 at 6
```

Comment: `if not x and y:` is more pythonic.

Comment: This is roughly the way I would have written it too! `zip` seems to be missing in the other answers above.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20groupby#itertools.groupby) to group the list into 0's and 1's:

```
from itertools import groupby

mot = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]

mot_daily_index = []
l = 0
for s, g in groupby(mot):
    if s == 1:
        mot_daily_index.append(l)
    l += len(list(g))

print(mot_daily_index)
```

Output:

```
[7, 24]
```

Answer (score 4):

```py
mot = [0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
mot_daily_index = [] # the required list
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    if a[i]==0 and a[i+1]==1:
        ind.append(i)
```

your code adds index whenever ith element is different from (i+1)th element

Answer (score 2):

- For a 3M element container, this answer is `67.2 times` faster than the accepted answer.
- This can be accomplished with `numpy`, by converting the `list` to a `numpy.array`.
- The code for his answer, is a modification of the code from [Find index where elements change value numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125661).

  - That question wanted all transitions `v[:-1] != v[1:]`, not just the small to large transitions, `v[:-1] < v[1:]`, in this question.
- Create a Boolean array, by comparing the array to itself, shifted by one place.
- Use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to return the indices for `True`

  - This finds the index before the change, because the arrays are shifted for comparison, so use `+1` to get the correct value.

```py
import numpy as np

v = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

# convert to array
v = np.array(v)

# create a Boolean array
map_ = v[:-1] < v[1:]

# return the indices
idx = np.where(map_)[0] + 1

print(idx)
[out]:
array([ 7, 24], dtype=int64)
```

### `%timeit`

```py
# v is 3M elements
v = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0] * 100000

# accepted answer
%timeit [i for i,m in enumerate(v) if i and m and not v[i-1]]
[out]:
336 ms ± 14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# this answer
v = np.array(v)
%timeit np.where(v[:-1] < v[1:])[0] + 1
[out]:
5.03 ms ± 85.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

A oneliner using `zip`:

```
mot = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]

[i+1 for i,m in enumerate(zip(mot[:-1],mot[1:])) if m[0]<m[1]]

# [7, 24]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another list comprehension take:

```
mot = [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]

change_mot = [index+1 for index, value in enumerate(zip(mot[:-1], mot[1:], )) if value[1] - value[0] == 1]
```

Which yields

```
[1, 8, 11, 15]
```

This picks up the increase and records the index only if the increase = 1.