# How to get the index dataframe that record the first changing

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have dataframe as bellow , I need to get the index of first changing value 0 in column y

```
x1  x2  y
12  7   1
0   3   0
5   11  1
7   2   1
4   8   1
1   0   0
5   0   0
0   9   0
2   2   1
```

So it would be some thing like this

```
x1  x2  y
0   3   0
1   0   0
```

I have tried this but it just print out the index where elements change

```
print(df.iloc[:,2].diff()[df.iloc[:,2].diff() != 0].index.values)
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried until now?

Comment: The logic is not entirely clear to me. Why `0   3   0` and `2   2   1` are not in your expected result? Why `12  7   0` and not `12  7   1`?

Comment: up to now I'm still looking for the answer but I tried to get the index only by doing as bellow
`print(df[2].diff()[df[2].diff() != 0].index.values)` but it gives all the index where elements change value but not specific '0' value @JeniDave

Comment: @alec_djinn I have reference to this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125661/find-index-where-elements-change-value-numpy)

Comment: @sweet1908 Then you have your question answered already there. pandas.DataFrame columns can be cast to numpy array, in your case `df.y.values`.